# What's better: including string class or using char arrays?

Tags: c++

for example I have project with 200 classes (200 headers and 200 compilatioin units),
each my class has members which hold some strings, mean I have to include string header from STL into each my header.

from another side I know I wouldn't need most of string class functionality(it's metods etc) in my compilation units.
that means each my compilation unit will have whole string class included but all I need is keyword "string".

compilation will take much longer! I will compile string class 200 times!

is it better in this case to use just char keyword or make some custom string class which will not be so big as string class is?

thanks.

Comment: I think this is precisely the issue the pre-compiled headers are designed to address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really should use std::string, because of many reasons:

- it is hard to write secure safe code with c-strings, but it is much easier with std::string
- the time it takes to compile `<string>` is tiny compared to total compilation time for a normal project
- should you really ever have to worry about the time it takes to compile the string header, you can always start using precompiled headers
- you get many functions for manipulating and searching in strings for free when you use std::string
- you don't really write c++ if you don't use the std library

Comment: OK, maybe I shouldn't ask this question and show the world what funy question is, but I don't give a flying f*k about that :D. thanks for informative answer.

Comment: "you don't really write c++ if you don't use the std library". Isn't it a bit of an overstatement?

Comment: That's certainly a valid question, but for me, C++ without the std library is just C on steroids with a bit of object orientation.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, modern IDEs can use precompiled headers to avoid this problem. Secondly, the cost of only 200 TUs including `<string>` is negligible. And thirdly, imagine the *incredible* amount of time you will lose having to deal with double deletes, memory leaks, and such, and the algorithmic cost of `strlen` being O(n) and that kind of mess.

Compile-time of moderate headers like `<string>` is *free* in comparison to the cost of not using such techniques.

Oh, and you can forward declare it if you genuinely don't need it's actual functionality.

Answer (score 0):

200 compilation units doesn't sound like a big project - I wouldn't sweat over it too much.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: The question just _begs_ for subjective answers

Answer (score 0):

Only you can decide if it's worth it. But you should know that the largest of large apps make plenty use of `std::string`, so I doubt that it's worth sacrificing it in favor of compile time. Don't under-estimate the benefits of sticking to `std::string`, and get used to C++ having a slow compile. 200 classes is small in the big picture.